# python lookup table

Tags: python

I have a need to create a lookup table where A=10 and Z=35(B=11, C=12 and so on), what's the easiest way to accomplish this in python? I know there must be a very easy way to do it, just can't seem to find it.

Comment: Do you want a lookup table from letters to numbers, numbers to letters, or both?

Comment: Am actually doing number to letter but got it figured out from the examples you and others posted below. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a look-up table – the expression

```
chr(c) - 54
```

(with `c` beinig the upper-case character) will do the trick.

Comment: I'd prefer `chr(c)-chr('A')+10`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: So do I, but when I was about to edit it in, Mark had already posted it. :)

Comment: ended up with something like this example. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

For a lookup table you can use a `dict`:

```
d = { 'A' : 10, 'Z' : 35 } # etc..
```

However in this case it seems there is a simple logical rule for calculating the result so instead of a lookup table you could just use a function with some simple arithmetic:

```
def letterToNumber(c):
    if not 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
         raise ValueError('invalid character: ' + c)
    return ord(c) - ord('A') + 10

def numberToLetter(x):
    if not 10 <= x <= 35:
         raise ValueError('invalid number: ' + x)
    return chr(x - 10 + ord('A'))
```

Answer (score 4):

I agree that a lookup table is unnecessary but here is one

```
>>> import string
>>> x = dict(zip(string.uppercase[:26],range(10,36)))
>>> x['A']
10
>>> x['Z']
35
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the straightforward approach:

```
import string

def make_lookup_table():
    "make a lookup table where 'A' -> 10, 'B' -> 11, ..., 'Z' -> 35"
    lookup_table = {}
    value = 10
    for letter in string.uppercase[:26]:
        lookup_table[letter] = value
        value += 1
```